# In Reform, how to compose a property with two values from a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, reform

I have a form object built with Reform and I would like to populate a property using two values that come from the form and they are not included in the model.

My form:

```
  div.form-item.form-item--near
    = f.input :employment_contract_type, collection: @presenter.employment_contract_codes_collection
    = f.input :employment_contract_time, collection: ["Partial", "Complete"], as: :radio_buttons
```

My form object:

```
  class FinancingRequestForm < Reform::Form
    property :employment_contract_code
    property :employment_contract_time, virtual: true
    property :employment_contract_type, virtual: true
  end
```

The model:

```
# Table name: purchase_financing_customers
#
#  id                       :integer          not null, primary key
#  employment_contract_code :string

module Purchase
  class FinancingCustomer < ApplicationRecord
  end
end
```

I would like something like this:

```
  class FinancingRequestForm < Reform::Form
    ContractCodePopulator = lambda do |_|
      time = employment_contract_type == "Complete" ? "C" : "P"
      self.employment_contract_code  = "#{send("employment_contract_type")}#{time}"
    end

    property :employment_contract_code, populator: ContractCodePopulator
    property :employment_contract_time, virtual: true
    property :employment_contract_type, virtual: true
  end
```

But the problem is that de Populator doesn't trigger when I run form.validate(request_params).

I just want the employment_contract_code composed with the other two virtual values.

Thanks!

Comment: Please do not use screen dumps from your editor. Instead copy the code itself into the question.

Comment: Ok, I thought the colored syntax was easier to read. I will add the code instead ;)